# list of hex strings to hex literals

Tags: python, python-3.x, literals

I have a hex string list:

```
lst = ['0x01', '0xfe', '0x02', '0xff']
```

I want to convert this list into a hex literal.

Output should be:

```
d = '\x01\xfe\x02\xff'
```

Comment: Did you tried `''.join(lst)`?

Comment: Yeah but it does not add the '\' to the d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to convert the string data to integers, then convert to bytes:

```
>>> lst = ['0x01','0xfe','0x02','0xff']
>>> d = bytes([int(x,0) for x in lst])
>>> d
b'\x01\xfe\x02\xff'
```

I'm assuming you really want a byte string here and not a Unicode string since it looks like byte data.

To make a *display* string, format a literal backslash and x with the hex value.  You could get the hex value by slicing the `0x` off the string, but for formatting consistency (e.g. two digits, lower case) you can still convert to integer and then use a format string:

```
>>> lst = ['0x43','0xfe','0x02','0xff']
>>> bytes([int(x,0) for x in lst]) # actual byte string shows printable ASCII
b'C\xfe\x02\xff'
>>> d = ''.join([f'\\x{int(v,0):02x}' for v in lst])  # display string of hex escape codes
>>> d
'\\x43\\xfe\\x02\\xff'
>>> print(d)
\x43\xfe\x02\xff
```

Comment: When I do this on a list that contains other hex values for example lst=['0x01','0xfe','0x02','0xff','0x56', '0x49','0x43'] it gives me b'\x01\xfe\x02\xffVIC' converts the 0x56, 0x49 and 0x43 to ASCII...is there a way to keep everything hex b'\x01\xfe\x02\xff\x056\x049\x043?

Comment: @magicsword Python displays printable bytes using their printable representations. Internally, `"\x043"` and `"C"` are identical.

Comment: @magicsword That's Python's default display of byte strings.  Printable ASCII bytes display as ASCII.  If you want to build a *display* string, I'll add to my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this.

```
print (''.join(['\\'+x for x in lst]))
```

The output of this will be:

```
\0x01\0xfe\0x02\0xff
```

If you want to remove the leading 0, then you can do something like this:

```
print((''.join(lst)).replace('0x',r'\x'))
```

It will give you:

```
\x01\xfe\x02\xff
```

Comment: Slightly simpler: `print(*['\\'+x for x in lst], sep='')`

Comment: Output need to be `'\x01\xfe\x02\xff'`, not `'\0x01\0xfe\0x02\0xff'`

Comment: I agree. Maybe this should help `print((''.join(lst)).replace('0x',r'\x'))`